jQuery html table searching multiple columns
The code given below works fine for searching a table. There is a single input box (id="name") in the html part, the table (15 columns, over 4000 rows), then the code:
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#name").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#data_table tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text()
                .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });

I have added a second input box (id="acc"). I would like to change the above code to make it capable of searching not only the name column but also the acc column.
I have already tried duplicating the part of the code $("#name").on("keyup", function() { + the next 6 lines, replacing "#name" by "#acc". This works, but searching for acc overrides the name search results. I expect the results to be additive.There must be a way of putting "#acc" into the script, but I cannot figure out how.

Michael Herdman  If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

You can use multiple ids in one go.
As you said different input box key-up needs to filter <tr> based on the corresponding column value match (which I assume <td> text match)
Add the same place-holder mapping the exact column class for each input box.
Add the same classes for each column that you want to search with the corresponding input box.
Now the below code works perfectly.
$(function() {
  $("#name,#age").on("keyup", function() {
    let tdClass = $(this).attr('placeholder'); // get placeholder value
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#data_table tbody tr").filter(function() {
    //use tdClass value as td class to filter row based on corresponding column text match
      $(this).toggle($(this).find("td."+tdClass).text()
        .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});

Working snippet:


$(function() {
  $("#name,#age").on("keyup", function() {
    let tdClass = $(this).attr('placeholder'); // get placeholder value
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#data_table tbody tr").filter(function() {
    //use tdClass value as td class to filter row based on corresponding column text match
      $(this).toggle($(this).find("td."+tdClass).text()
        .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
.search_field {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#data_table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#data_table td, #data_table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#data_table tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#data_table tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#data_table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<input id="name" placeholder="name" class="search_field">
<input id="age" placeholder="age" class="search_field">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<table id="data_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Alive-to-die</td><!-- add class with same placeholder name -->
      <td class="age">66</td>
      <td>alivetodie@dummyid.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Michael Herdman</td>
      <td class="age">25</td>
      <td>michaelherdman@dummyid.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>




Michael Herdman "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's How does accepting an answer work?. Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"
